# How do you clean Redgard off your brush and roller?

Tags: tools, cleaning

I just finished applying Redgard on two walls
I need to clean up the roller and the brush ...how do I do that ?
Acetone based solution ? Any other dissolvent?

Comment: what are the cleanup instructions on the product container?

Comment: also check the material datasheet

Comment: Please don't feel like questions are unwelcome.  I think the people nudging you toward "read the instructions" are more concerned with your legal obligation to *follow* the instructions.   on products like these, it's legally mandatory to *follow* the instructions. (which requires you *read* them obviously).

Comment: not a problem ...I did read that but somehow I missed that line. Discovered that by accident :-) (trial and error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the technical data sheet](https://www.custombuildingproducts.com/TDS/TDS-104.pdf):

> **Cleaning of equipment**
>
> Clean tools and hands with water before the material dries. Clean all
> spray equipment immediately after use.

Which to me means: If you don't do it right away, the work involved to clean it is probably more than the rollers and brush are worth. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that immersing the brush and the roller in water solves the problem, it will disolve if it still soft/wet